# Evitar agregar un valor si ese mismo ya se encuentra en un array

Tags: javascript, array

soy un poco nueva en JS y actualmente estoy realizando un sitio web para una tienda en linea, lo estoy intentando es que al hacer clic en un botón, solo se pueda agregar una única vez un mismo producto al  array de mi carrito de compras, por lo que he investigado, se que puedo utilizar el método `includes()` para ver si mi array incluye ya el valor que pido, y si no es el caso, agregarlo, pero no logro hacer que me funcione y sinceramente no se si es lo mas optimo.

Este es el código del botón; no esta declarado aquí, pero el array comprasdata es un array vacío.

```js
var dtmp = comprasdata.value;
var mdata = [];
for (const obj of dtmp) {
    mdata.push(obj);
}
mdata.push({
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Alcancia Azul",
  "precio": "100",
 });

turno.run();
invp2.run();

if(!mdata.includes("Alcancia Azul") && turno.data[0]["Turno"]==12 && invp2.data[0]["cantidad"]>0){
  comprasdata.setValue(mdata);
  }else if(!mdata.includes("Alcancia Azul") && turno.data[0]["Turno"]==20 && invp2.data[0]["cantinoche"]>0){
  comprasdata.setValue(mdata);
  }else{
  window.alert("Producto agotado");
}
```

Siento que el problema es que debo especificar el valor que no quiero que se incluya en `!mdata.includes("Alcancia Azul")`, o que debo mover la posición mi `mdata.push()`. Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Esta es la primera pregunta que realizo en este sitio, lamento de antemano si no cumplí las reglas para las preguntas o si no he sido muy clara al exponer mis dudas. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `includes()` te serviría para buscar en un array de **números**, o de **strings**. Para buscar en un array de **objetos**, como el que tienes, yo usaría el método `find()`.

```js
var mdata = [];

mdata.push({
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Alcancia Azul",
  "precio": "100",
 });

if (mdata.find((producto) => producto.name === 'Alcancia Azul')) {
  console.log('Se encuentra')
}
else {
  console.log('No se encuentra')
}
```

**Referencia:** [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)